# POST requests in axios for creating object in django restframework api

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios

I am working with APIs and currently have created a restframework API for creating and view posts that belong to a user. A post has a text field and a favorite-tags field.

My posts view is a class based view defined as - 
`class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView)`

I am using `vue.js` for the frontend and I am able to make a successful get request from the frontend as follows:

```
this.$http.get('posts/',{headers: {Authorization: 'Token ' + this.$store.getters.getToken }})
```

However, I am not sure how to send the data of the post to the backend in this call for the restframework api. How can I send a text field from the frontend.

Currently when I try something like this :

```
this.$http.post('posts/',{headers: {Authorization: 'Token ' + this.$store.getters.getToken }, data: {'text': 'asdasd' }})
```

I am getting `401` status code error

Comment: Can you post your views so it would be easier to inspect where the problem lies?

Comment: Hi! I've added the posts view as well in the original post now as well. you may check it out

Comment: And what exception does Django prints?

Comment: Can you verify that your token is valid? 401 response code means "Unauthorized".

Comment: I believe my token is valid because I used the same token and made the same request on postman and it worked. Im guessing that based on that, it has something to do with my format.

Comment: `this.$store.getters.token` is better than `this.$store.getters.getToken`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this work?

```
this.$http.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    const token=this.$store.getters.getToken;
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = "Token " + token;
    }
    return config;
  }
);
this.$http.post('posts/', {'text': 'asdasd'})
```

Comment: OMG thanks! this works!. However, can you please explain what exactly is the difference that is causing this to work and not my code?